# How to avoid &quot; returned from twing

Tags: twig, twing

I am using twig as below

```js
res.render("screen/index.twig", {
    name: 'word',
    columns: columns,
});
```

It is working as excepted.

Now I want to switch to twing and  used below code

```js
const contents = await twing
.render("screen/index.twig", {
  name: 'word',
  columns: columns,
})
res.end(contents);
```

here contents give below

```
...
  <script>
    window.COLUMNS = [{&quot;alignment&quot;:&quot;left&quot;}];
  </script>
...
```

But I need the below output without using any `.replace` function. How can I achieve this? Can anyone tell why it working in `twig` and not in `twing`? Thanks.

```
...
  <script>
    window.COLUMNS = [{"alignment":"left"}];
  </script>
...
```

Comment: Please post the actual template, `index.twig`! As far as I can see you're missing the filter `raw`, but can't tell w/out seeing the template

Comment: Yes. `raw` is missing. i.e. I have changed `window.COLUMNS = {{ columns | json_encode()}};`  to `window.COLUMNS = {{ columns | json_encode() | raw}};` in `index.twig` and the `&quot;` is gone. Thanks. But why raw is not needed in twig?  i.e. Why does Twig not have this problem? Why is Twing not doing this automatically?

Comment: I'm not sure which version you were testing this on, but it is needed in `twig` as well - [demo](https://twigfiddle.com/6501q0)

Comment: @DarkBee please check this question once and help me to solve the same. Thanks once again.

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70346658/how-to-use-direct-path-of-file-without-declaring-folder-path-twing